Distorted Line Chart while moving RuleMark Selector
I was able to code a line chart and everything is going well. Next I wanted to add a RuleMark selector so that when I move across the line chart I can see the values drawn on the line chart. The problem is that the RuleMark works well on the first two point on the chart, then it stops. As I progress further the values in the annotation are displayed correctly, but the line chart gets distorted as I move along. The Y values gets attached to the stopped RuleMark selector in the beginning and distorts the curve. The selector doesn't move any further. Any ideas? How can I fix it? How can I make the selector progress further along the entire curve? Thanks in advance.
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct RigsYTDChartiPadOS: View {
    @ObservedObject var variables: Variables
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    @State private var lineSelection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Close")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .frame(width: 70)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 20)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
                    withAnimation {
                        variables.showYTDChart.toggle()
                    }
                })
                .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
                .background(.secondary)
                
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Expand")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .frame(width: 70)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 20)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
                    variables.showYTDChart = false
                })
                .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
                .background(.secondary)
            }
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("\(variables.selectedRig) Tripping YTD Flat Time")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                
                //                GeometryReader
                //                {
                //                    geometry in
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0)
                {
                    
                    let tempMaxYaxis = (variables.rigsYTDTrippingKPIs.map { $0.flatTime }.max() ?? 0)
                    let tempMinYaxis = (variables.rigsYTDTrippingKPIs.map { $0.flatTime }.min() ?? 0)
                    let minYaxis = (tempMinYaxis > 0 ? 0 : tempMinYaxis)
                    let maxYaxis = (tempMaxYaxis < 0 || minYaxis  == tempMaxYaxis ? 0 : tempMaxYaxis)
                    let count = variables.rigsYTDTrippingKPIs.count
                    
                    var stops: [Gradient.Stop] {
                        let reference = 0.0 // Or whichever your threshold is
                        let minimum = minYaxis
                        let maximum = maxYaxis
                        let denominator  = maximum - minimum
                        let nominator = reference - minimum
                        let result = nominator / denominator
                        let positiveColor = Color(red: 0.643, green: 0.031, blue: 0)
                        let negativeColor = Color(red: 0, green: 0.431, blue: 0.016)
                        
                        return [Gradient.Stop(color: positiveColor, location: 0.0),
                                Gradient.Stop(color: positiveColor, location: result),
                                Gradient.Stop(color: negativeColor, location: result + 0.0001),
                                Gradient.Stop(color: negativeColor, location: 1.0)]
                    }
                    
                    let graphLineColor = Color(red: 0, green: 0.431, blue: 0.016)
                    
                    let graphLineAreaGradient = LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(
                            colors: [
                                graphLineColor.opacity(0.6),
                                graphLineColor.opacity(0.1),
                                .clear
                            ]
                        )
                        , startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom
                    )
                    
                    Chart{
                        
                        ForEach(variables.rigsYTDTrippingKPIs) { item in
                            
                            AreaMark(
                                x: .value("Date", item.reportDate),
                                y: .value("Flat Time", /*item.animate ?*/ item.flatTime /*: 0*/)
                            )
                            .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
                            .foregroundStyle(graphLineAreaGradient)
                            
                            LineMark(
                                x: .value("Date", item.reportDate),
                                y: .value("Flat Time", /*item.animate ?*/ item.flatTime /*: 0*/)
                            )
                            .interpolationMethod(.cardinal)
                            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(stops: stops, startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
                            
                            if let lineSelection {
                                RuleMark(
                                    x: .value("Date", lineSelection)
                                )
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                                .offset(yStart: -10)
                                .zIndex(-1)
                                .annotation(
                                    position: .top, spacing: 0,
                                    overflowResolution: .init(
                                        x: .fit(to: .chart),
                                        y: .disabled
                                    )
                                ) {
                                    //                                        valueSelectionPopover
                                    Text("Lets See \(lineSelection)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .chartXSelection(value: $lineSelection)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)
                    .chartYScale(domain: minYaxis...maxYaxis)
                    .frame(height: .infinity)
                    .chartXAxis{
                        let dates = variables.rigsYTDTrippingKPIs.map{$0.reportDate}
                        AxisMarks (preset: .automatic, position: .bottom)
                        { data in
                            AxisGridLine()
                            let value = dates[data.index]
                            AxisValueLabel(centered: true, collisionResolution: .truncate,
                                           orientation: AxisValueLabelOrientation.horizontal){
                                Text(value)
                                //                                        .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / IntToCGFloat(v: count)!!), alignment: .center)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                                           .font(.system(size: 8))
                                           .foregroundStyle(Color.white.opacity(0.6))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 3)
                    .chartYAxis {
                        AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 3)) {
                            let value = $0.as(Double.self)!
                            AxisValueLabel {
                                Text("\(String(format: "%.0f", (value * 100)))%")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                //                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                .cornerRadius(15)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
    
    func IntToCGFloat(v: Int??) -> CGFloat?? {
        v.flatMap { $0.flatMap { CGFloat($0) } }
    }
}


Please see the code and picture to realize the problem
Line Chart Distorted Snapshot

Try moving the RuleMark out of the ForEach.

That's it!!!!! That was the problem!!!! Thanks a lot Sweeper! Ok if you can help me out with one last thing, how can I include the y value displayed on the line chart in the annotation of the RuleMark?

There is no magic. You just have to search through your data and find the closest one to the selected x value.

Sweeper, I know it sounds easy, but I'm not so advanced with swiftui and I'm still learning. If you can help me to modify the above code to display the flatTime as well, I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot

For additional help, please open another question with a small reproducible example.
